How to add class of relation to @ManyToMany relation before save data. (DETACHED PROBLEM)
I am trying to add UserGroups to User table on Hibernate Spring Data JPA

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@ProtoClass(UserProtos.User.class)
public class TblUser extends DatabaseObjectProperties {

    @ProtoField
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "user_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_seq", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private int idUser;

    @ProtoField
    @NotEmpty(message = "UserName must not be empty.")
    private String userName;

    @ProtoField
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password must not be empty.")
    private String password;

    @ProtoField
    @NotEmpty(message = "First name must not be empty.")
    private String firstName;

    @ProtoField
    @NotEmpty(message = "Last Name must not be empty.")
    private String lastName;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "rltUserToUserGroup",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName = "idUser"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user_group", referencedColumnName = "idUserGroup")
    )
    private final Set<TblUserGroup> userGroupsAtUser = new HashSet<>();

As you can see, I am using ManyToMany relationship between TblUser and TblUserGroup.
TblUser tblUser = Converter.create().toDomain(TblUser.class, user); // Created Object
// ..
for (TblUserGroup userGroup : allAssignedGroups) {
    tblUser.getUserGroupsAtUser().add(userGroup);
}
userRepository.save(tblUser);

I know if I do like that, it solved.
TblUser tblUser = Converter.create().toDomain(TblUser.class, user); // Created Object
// ..
tblUser = userRepository.save(tblUser);
for (TblUserGroup userGroup : allAssignedGroups) {
    tblUser.getUserGroupsAtUser().add(userGroup);
}
userRepository.save(tblUser);

But generating before inserting is better I guess because double inserting to database has cost. I thought @PrePersist callback can be solution but I guess I cannot optimize this. Pooling is good option on next stages. What do you recommend? Thank you so much.
